# martingale stopping time is same as total number of events?

Tags: martingales, stopping-times

$X:=\{X_n\}_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence of i.i.d random variables with
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\left(X_1=1\right)=p\in (0,1)\setminus \{\frac{1}{2}\} \text{ and } \mathbb P\left(X_1=-1\right)=q=(1-p)    
\end{align*}
Define $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} X_k$. Show that

\item [a)] $Y_n=\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^{S_n}$ is a martingale with respect to natural filtration of $X$.

\item[b)] $a, b\in \mathbb Z, a<0<b$ and define $\tau:=\inf\{ n\ge 0: S_n\in \{a,b\}\}$. Then show that $\left(Y_{\tau\wedge n}\right)_{n\ge 0}$ is uniformly integrable.

\item[c)] Assuming $\mathbb P\left(\tau<\infty\right)=1$, show that
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P\left(S_{\tau}=a\right)=\frac{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^b}{\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^a-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^b}
\end{align*}

I did (a) perfectly, I am not able to understand (b) at all, and what I need to show and how?

for (c) I am able to prove  \begin{align*}
\mathbb P\left(\tau=\tau_a\right)=\frac{1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^b}{\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^a-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)^b}
\end{align*}
but I don't know how to show what is asked. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(b) $\{Y_{\tau\wedge n}\}$ is bounded (and, thus, [u.i.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Related_corollaries)):
$$
\sup_{n\ge 1}|Y_{\tau\wedge n}|\le \max((q/p)^b,(q/p)^a).
$$
(c) $S_{\tau}=a$ on $\{\tau=\tau_a\}$ ($\because\tau=\tau_a\wedge \tau_b$).

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit (c)?

Comment: Also, I was just wondering what is the expression for $Y_{\tau \wedge n}$?

Comment: Write
$$
\mathsf{P}(S_{\tau}=a)=\mathsf{P}(\{S_{\tau}=a\}\cap\{\tau=\tau_a\})+\mathsf{P}(\{S_{\tau}=a\}\cap\{\tau=\tau_b\})=\mathsf{P}(\tau=\tau_a)+0.
$$

Comment: $Y_{\tau\wedge n}=Y_{\tau}$ on $\{\tau<n\}$ and $=Y_n$ on $\{\tau\ge n\}$.